# Segmentation fault, release configuration only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when building in release configuration, but not in debug configuration.

This code is a bundle that gets loaded at run time. The crash itself happens before any of my is executed (implying the compiler is producing a malformed binary, almost certainly because of a problem in my code). The crash happens in this function: paranoid_check_one_class

The code below causes no problems, but if I uncomment the two lines that are commented out, then I get the crash. (I can comment out `firstName`, `lastName` or `company` to make it work, it just doesn't like all three)

```
-(NSArray *)specifiersForContacts {
    NSMutableArray *contactSpecs = [NSMutableArray array];
    ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    for (NSNumber *contactID in [self contacts]) {
        ABRecordRef contact = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(book,[contactID intValue]);
        NSString *firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contact, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contact, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
      //NSString *company = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contact, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);
        NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName ?: @"", company ?: @""];
        PSSpecifier *contactSpec = [PSSpecifier preferenceSpecifierNamed:fullName
                                                              target:self
                                                                 set:NULL
                                                                 get:NULL
                                                              detail:Nil
                                                                cell:13
                                                                edit:Nil];
        [contactSpec setValues:@[contactID]];
        [contactSpec setProperty:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"alignment"];
        [firstName release];
        [lastName release];
      //[company release];
        [contactSpecs addObject:contactSpec];
    }
    return [[contactSpecs copy] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: does it crash if you retrieve some other property, like middle name?

Comment: the property doesnt matter, its how many i retrieve, it also crashes on other c functions (addressbook ones anyway)

Comment: and if you don't retrieve it, but just make up a string for company (nsstringwithformat)?